# Sharing the same page on facebook with different titles/photos

Tags: facebook, share

I have many photos on the page and I'd like to add like buttons to them, so I created a page photo.php?id=x and link like buttons to it with different variabiles. But fb removes all variabiles after posting! About 1 year ago it was working, but now I can`t add variabiles in link to share.

There is another way to share the page with different ID?

```
echo '<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fportovenere.a-turist.com%2F'.$curfolder.'photo.php%3Fid%3D'.$row["id"].'&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';
```

P.S.:

```
$curfolder="ru/"
id = 1-5 for test
```

or

```
echo '<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.portovenere.a-turist.com/'.$curfolder.'photo.php?id='.$row["id"].'" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="150" data-show-faces="true"></div>';
```

with this one: it share a page with variabiles but doesn`t pick up info (photo, title)

or old sharer:

```
echo '<a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://portovenere.a-turist.com/'.$curfolder.'photo.php?id='.$row["id"].'"><img style="margin-bottom:25px;" src="/images/fb_share_img.png"></a>';
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are using, what is the url you're giving to the like button?

Comment: Make sure that your url is url-encoded and that the facebook parts are not. It seems like you kind of confused things with the encoding.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? I tried to insert link: <..>/like.php?href=http://portovenere.a-turist.com/ru/photo.php?id='.$row["id"].'&amp;send=false<..> it doesn`t help

Comment: Try to take a url of your for testing (full url) and use this [URL Decoder/Encoder](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/). Put the url in the textarea and click the `Encode` button, take the result and put it in the like button and see if it works.

Comment: just tried, no, it doesn`t work, I tried it already becouse fb button creator use encoding. but it removes all variabiles... I have an old site in which the same script was working but about 6 month ago it was broken without any change by me...

Comment: the only thing I found for the moment is to create 1000+ pages, 1 for every photo on every language, and use <meta http-equiv="refresh"> but its crazy way

Comment: Can you please give me a url of yours for testing?

Comment: http://portovenere.a-turist.com/photo_galery.php here... but all buttons links to /ru/photo.php without ?id= and choose random photo (my script if there is no id = random photo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your problem is with the `og:url` meta tag.

Check out what the [debug tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://portovenere.a-turist.com/photo_galery.php?id=4) says about your url:

> Fetched URL:  http://portovenere.a-turist.com/photo_galery.php?id=4
>   Canonical URL:    http://www.portovenere.a-turist.com/photo_galery.php

I believe that if you fix that and return the same url for the `og:url` it will behave as you want it.

Comment: Thank you! It works with old sharer, so I use it... Like button doesn`t work for the moment, but some problems was there. Will test it now more:)